# Fixed dimension Integer programming minus LLL in fixed parameter $NC$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, dc.parallel-comp, integer-programming, fixed-parameter-tractable, comp-number-theory

> If you remove LLL part then is remaining part of
>
> a. Lenstra algorithm
>
> b. Barvinok algorithm
>
> in $O(f(n)(\log(mL))^c)$ time on $O(g(n)(mL)^c)$ processors with fixed $c>0$ in fixed $n$ dimension, $m$ constraints and $L$ bit length input for some functions $f,g:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$?

Note we know linear programming and convex programming are not in $NC$ in general dimension.

In fact if we remove $LLL$ are these in $Logspace$?

Comment: I assume for your last comment you mean assuming $P \neq NC$?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow yes that is correct.